# continuity and circle

Tags: limits, continuity, circles

$f(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x^{2}+y^{2} & \text { if } x^{2}+y^{2}<1 \\ 1 & \text { if } x^{2}+y^{2} \geq 1\end{array}\right.$

Is this function continuous ? It seems like it is circle of radius 1 which is continuous. But I am not sure about it and I have seen this type of continuity problem first time.

Comment: It is a 3D shape.

Comment: It may help to think of this as $f(x,y) = \min[x^2+y^2,1]$, which is a composition of functions. That is $$f(x,y) = g(h(x,y))$$ where $h(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ and $g(z) = \min[z,1]$.

Comment: Alternatively you could argue it is continuous at a point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ by using the definition and considering the three cases (i) $x^2+y^2<1$; (ii) $x^2+y^2>1$; (iii) $x^2+y^2=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+y^2 \lt 1$ inside the unit circle centered at the origin. You can check that $\lim_{(x^2+y^2)\to 1^-} f(x,y)=1$, and so the function is indeed continuous.

[image]

Notice that the curve is a paraboloid inside the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and the plane $z=1$ otherwise.